# Why does "variable might not have been initialized" prevent compile?

Tags: java

```
myObj a;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;

if(b == c) {
    a = new myObj(5);
    b = 2;
}

if(a.getValue() == 5) {
    ....
}
```

Even though `a` will always have been initialized when it reaches the second if statement, I will still be unable to compile the program unless I declare it at start.

Also, if I put `myObj a = null`, it *will* work, which is basically the same as if I just left it as `myObj`, but *not* give an error or prevent compile.

Why is "variable might not have been initialized" an error that prevents compile, instead of just a warning? What is the difference between `myObj a;` and `myObj a = null;`?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257857/what-is-the-difference-between-uninitialized-object-variable-and-object-variable

Comment: I suppose it's only there to help programmers catch possible bugs (you usually want to avoid NREs).

Comment: `myObj a;` has no value at all.  It'll just be random junk on the stack if you don't put a value there.  You have to null it manually (unlike instance and class variables).

Comment: Java is a "safe" language. It won't let you access data that has not been initialized. The same situation in C would read undefined data. That is not very desirable.

Comment: You could also move the `if(a.getValue() == 5) {` inside the `if` where you **initialize** `a`. The compiler is detecting a (valid) *possible* fatal error.

Comment: You seem to be asking both why initialized access is an error and why the compiler doesn't analyze your condition at compile-time. Please clarify your question to one point or the other.

Comment: There is no reason for a variable to exists if it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is "variable might not have been initialized" an error that prevents compile, instead of just a warning?

Because warnings tend to be ignored, and Java designers knew it. This is a relatively easy catch with a trivial fix, so the cost of erroring out is zero.

> What is the difference between "myObj a;" and "myObj a = null;"?

The second declaration says "I thought about the initial value, and it's going to be null."

The first declaration says "I have not made up my mind about the initial value yet; maybe later."

Your case is interesting, because the value is always going to be set, it's just that the compiler is not smart enough to see it.

Comment: It is pretty much by design that the compiler is not smart enough to see it :)